# How to monitor whether the div is updated or not using jquery?

Tags: jquery, events, html

My Div have the contenteditable as true, but I would like to monitor the div, if there is updated. How can I monitor it using jquery? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look into *mutation events* for that purpose. In your case

```
$('#myDIV').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(e) {
});
```

That should fire every time, anything changes within that DOM subtree. I'm not sure if it works with a contentEditable however.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/J6ARW/

**One word of caution**: Mutation events were declared 'deprecated' so it might be a nice tool to play around with, but maybe not wise to use for any production code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.blur()` or the `.keypress()` event handling methods..

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/nwCsr/

---

**Update**

to handle paste you can listen for the `paste` event..

```
$('selector').bind('paste', function(){
  // handle paste ..
});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/nwCsr/1/

Comment: keypress doesn't work, because if the user paste it, I can't capture it.

Comment: @TedWong you can use the `.bind('paste', function(){..})` to handle the `paste` event..

Answer (score 0):

you should use `setInterval()` and check every second or so if the div is changed. If you're using AJAX, you could trigger the change event when the AJAX is complete. Also, I think you can use the `onKeyPressed` or `onKeyUp` event for that div.